# How do I dynamically deliver a user to the correct regional website?

Tags: asp.net, region, geotargetting

I've been able to find a lot of information on multi-region websites and their SEO setup, but i cannot find much about development for these type of sites.  If a customer in Australia goes directly to the top level .com version of the website, are there methods I can use to redirect them to their regional version of the website?  How reliable are they?

When building these type of site do you usually just have one website with multiple domains (eg. example.com, example.au, example.uk), then swap content/language dynamically based on the url it's being accessed by?

Comment: this depends on what your goal is.  Are you trying to target a user's location or are you trying to localize the site (different spellings, number formatting, etc.)?

Comment: I don't like posting links as answers so I won't.  There are some great resources on Hanselman's blog (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx), GeoLite is a great tool for mapping source IP to country (combined with culture) can be quite efficient, in my experience most sites use culture in the url.

Comment: The goal is to serve up different content, language, and url based on the country and language settings a user is visiting from... I thought about using something like this API to determine the country http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php, and possibly the browser's preferred language settings to determine language.I assume i should treat these separately because a candian user should only see certain products but may want to read the site in English or French.